# Yahoo Sign-In Option appears to be broken

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login

I use primarily the Yahoo OpenId sign in option for my StackOverflow account.  Typically, I spend way more time on SO than meta (meaning I rarely have to re-login on SO).  When I switch from SO to meta, I usually always get the "You have been logged in - click here to refresh message".  Tonight I am not getting that message.  Additionally, when I attempt to login with the yahoo endpoint in either meta or SO (by clicking on the more options, then the Yahoo! icon), I receive the following message (after a 30 second-ish wait)

[image]

[image]

Setup:

OS - Windows 8.1
Browsers: Chrome 32.0.1700.107m and IE 11.0.9600.16476

Luckily, I recently attached my Facebook login as well to my SE credentials, which enabled me to login and ask this question.

**EDIT**

After 20 minutes or so from my initial question - attempting to login with IE renders the following response from Yahoo!

[image]

It appears that either Yahoo! or SE is changing some configurations (maybe?) and the two are not talking well with each other anymore.

Comment: Downvoter - any reason why?  I can replicate this issue across multiple browsers, I asked a well formed question with screenshots showing the error I am receiving.  What makes this a "bad question"?

Comment: Some people automatically assume that, if you're reporting login problems, you're doing it wrong. Don't worry too much about it - people are silly sometimes.

Comment: @Emracool - I never mind down-votes if warrented, but I like to know what they think I did poorly so that I can improve in the future :)

Comment: In this case, it's probably nothing to worry about :] This bug report is about as detailed as we could possibly hope to receive, so +1.

Comment: There was a problem using Yahoo, but it seems to be working again - they must have fixed it on their end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some investigation on this earlier, and it appears that Yahoo had smashed its [Yadis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YADIS) headers.

I can confirm that no changes happened on the Stack Exchange side, so the fix must have been at Yahoo.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I assumed as much, but in case it was tied to the meta changeover / removing the myOpenId option, I wanted to report so that the issue surfaced.

Comment: Hey Kevin can you please take a look on [this one as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221313/152859)?