# Stack Overflow login via Yahoo! is broken

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login, openid, yahoo

For the past one or two days, I haven't been able to log into my Stack Overflow account. It is associated with a Yahoo! login. I am getting this error:

[image]

So I assumed I have the same problem as [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220430/yahoo-sign-in-option-appears-to-be-broken), but then that question is closed, and the issue is said to be resolved.

Strangely, I could log into the Meta Stack Overflow (and its login screen is layouted slightly different), so I could post the question. But I can't get back to Stack Overflow itself. This is with Firefox 27 (Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)), cookie permissions are given to Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange.

Comment: If you know the full address of your yahoo openId, you can use that (should be something like https://me.yahoo.com/<something you chose>

Comment: How would I find that out? I try randomly my e-mail address etc., all I get is "No OpenID endpoint found"...

Comment: @0__ read [this](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-account/openid-sln2062.html), does it help?

Comment: N.B. Japanese Yahoo has no support too.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, thanks, I found my openID there, but entering it directly doesn't change anything. I also tried creating a customized ID through that page, but Yahoo! only reports: "Sorry! We have encountered an error that prevents us from fulfilling your request. Things should return to normal soon, so please try your request again in a few minutes."

Comment: Weird... hope a dev would be able to shed some light over this soon.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - something on the Yahoo end was borked. It seems to be working again now, though I would like the OP to confirm.

Comment: @Oded yeah, looks like Yahoo need to be more careful when changing stuff, they keep breaking those things.

Answer (score 3):

I asked Stack Exchange for help. The reply was along the lines "this is a problem of Yahoo! and we cannot do anything about it."

Since I could still log into meta.stackoverflow, I signed up for a Stack Exchange login, and luckily it was *added* to my existing account. So I can use that login now instead of Yahoo!.